# Использование собачки, чтобы пришло уведомление человеку

Tags: поддержка

Кто-то говорил, что уведомление о сообщении собеседник получает, только если у тебя появляется подсказка с его именем и ты её выбираешь. А когда вручную прописываешь собачку с именем, тогда не появляется. Просто у меня подсказку предлагает компьютер, а телефон — нет. Действительно тогда не доходит, если вручную прописываешь, и что с этим тогда делать?

И ещё мне говорили, что если ставишь знак препинания после имени с собачкой, то сообщение не доходит адресату. Однако на [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) мне ставили двоеточие после них и уведомления приходили. И один из лидеров рейтинга на том сайте так постоянно делает, я думаю, он бы давно понял, если бы это не работало, что пора перестать так делать.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, какие-то частные наблюдения были кем-то неправильно обобщены.

Я думаю, что уведомления не приходят только в том случае, когда адресат сообщения не участвовал в данном (локальном) обсуждении. Для примера, я сделаю несколько упоминаний здесь и в комментарии — любопытно, какие из них дойдут. Мой прогноз: не будет ни одного уведомления.
@АртёмЛуговой
@Артём

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Тест

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly! Об ответе только пришло уведомление. А как вы думаете, если прописываешь вручную (как с телефона) тому, кто участвует в обсуждении, ему доходит? Или думаете, что и без собачки всё равно обязательно приходит? Мне не пришло в комментариях, когда собеседник один раз не прописал этого обращения (а до этого прописывал).

Comment: Собачка обязательна. Я говорил только, что набираю обращение с собачкой, а не пользуюсь выбором (мне так быстрее). Без собачки наличие имени не играет роли. А на вот этот комментарий без имени и без собачки скорее всего вы получите уведомление. Это потому, что вы единственный теоретически возможный адресат. Но этот вариант может сбоить, поэтому им лучше не злоупотреблять.

Comment: Ага, сработал! Значит, можно набирать, а не выбирать, и это работает, да?

Comment: Да, можно набирать.

Comment: Гризли, а на первый тест мне не пришло ничего, потому что я тогда ещё не комментировал ваш ответ?

Answer (score 0):

- Уведомление придёт, если пользователь, к которому вы обращаетесь, писал комментарий под этим же вопросом/ответом. Если напишете @имяпользователя в ответе, то ничего не произойдёт.
- Между собачкой и ником пользователя не должно быть пробелов или любых других символов.
- После никнейма пользователя должен быть пробел, и только потом знак препинания или текст комментария.
- Если в никнейме пользователя есть пробелы, то они убираются.
- Как выяснилось, можно ещё ставить двоеточие после никнейма (`@username:`). Вероятно, это как-то связано с ответом на сообщение в чате: там ставится двоеточие + `id` сообщения (`:12345`) и это отображается как `@name_of_user`, но позволяет узнать, на какое именно сообщение в чате отвечает это сообщение.

Comment: Я спрашивал про знаки препинания ещё.

Comment: Почитайте, в каком месте знаки препинания!

Comment: Перечитали мой вопрос?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: вам не придёт уведомление

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой : а так придёт

Comment: **Оба пришли!** На английском сайте мы часто ставим двоеточие без пробела в конце и всё приходит!

Comment: Прочитайте, я там дописал. Нет, все три пришли. Имел в виду оба до того, что дополнили.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: пришло?

Comment: агась))))))))))